# Maximum of $(\sin{x} + \sqrt3)(\cos{x}+1)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

The problem is

> Maximum of $(\sin{x} + \sqrt3) (\cos{x}+1)$

I tried to set $\sin(t) = y$, $\cos(t) = x$, so that the problem turned out to be finding

Max $(y + \sqrt3)(x + 1)$

s.t. $x^2 + y^2 =1 $

I tried Lagrange multipliers, but it turns out to be a quartic equation.

I also tried a linear transformation such that the problem becomes

Max $x^2 - y^2$

s.t. $(x + \frac{\sqrt3+1}{2})^2 + (y - \frac{\sqrt3-1}{2})^2 = 1$

Since $x^2-y^2$ is saddle surface, the answer is still not trivial.

Can you help me find the way out?

Comment: Since it is in one variable, why not just differentiate wrt x the original expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can proceed by [tangent half angle identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) to obtain

$$f(t)=\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^2} + \sqrt3\right)  \left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} + 1\right) \implies f'(t)=-4\frac{\sqrt 3t^3+3t^2+\sqrt 3t-1}{(1+t^2)^3}$$

and since

$$g(t)=\sqrt 3t^3+3t^2+\sqrt 3t-1 \implies g'(t)=3\sqrt 3t^2+6t+\sqrt 3=3\sqrt 3\left(t+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)^2\ge 0$$

we have that $f'(t)$ has only one root which corresponds to the maximum for $f(t)$.

Now since

$$g'(t)=3\sqrt 3\left(t+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)^2 \implies g(t)=\sqrt 3\left(t+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)^3+c$$

expanding we find $c=-\frac43$ therefore the root is given by

$$\sqrt 3\left(t+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)^3=\frac43 \implies t\approx 0.339$$

Comment: I tried tangent identities and failed to solve the cubic equation. The integral trick is marvellous! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye